# Error while compiling linphone android

Tags: android, makefile, linphone

I am getting this error when I try to compile linphone source

> configure: creating ./config.status
>   config.status: error: cannot find input file: `Makefile.in'
>   make: *** [/Users/macbook/linphone-android/submodules/libilbc-rfc3951/Makefile] Error 1

I already have installed libtool.
I already have tried replacing

```
if test -f /opt/local/bin/glibtoolize ; then
# darwin
LIBTOOLIZE=/opt/local/bin/glibtoolize
```

with

```
if test -f /usr/local/bin/glibtoolize ; then
# darwin
LIBTOOLIZE=/usr/local/bin/glibtoolize
```

but still no use.
Can anyone please put me on right track.

I am using Mac OS.

Comment: Hi, just checking, manage to find any solutions? I'm stuck at the same step as you.

Comment: Nope, I shifted on windows machine.

Comment: Sorry, but do you have a good tutorial I can follow to get the source code and working on a windows machine? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same issue on Mac using GNU automake 1.15.
Looks like something's wrong somewhere between autotools and the libilc-rfc3951 submodule. Run those commands and you will be ready to compile:

```
$ cd /Users/macbook/linphone-android/submodules/libilbc-rfc3951
$ libtoolize (or glibtoolize)
$ aclocal
$ automake
```